# How to rename mongoDB columns big data?

Tags: mongodb, rename

I have a database with 15,574,934 records in mongo

I want to rename some columns to:

```
db.offerPhotos.files.update({}, {$rename: { 'orgFilename': 'metadata.orgFilename', 'offerId': 'metadata.offerId', 'batch': 'metadata.batch', 'group': 'metadata.group', 'size': 'metadata.size', 'mimeType': 'metadata.mimeType'}}, false, true)
```

I do it by mongo CLI but I'm waiting and waiting and nothing happens

How to do it better?

Comment: why you are using dot in your new name like metadata.offerId?

Answer (score 2):

As per [MongDB naming conventions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

1. Field names **cannot** contain the null character.
2. Top-level field names **cannot** start with the dollar sign ($) character.

The use of `$` and `.` in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers

> Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of
> field names that contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

Comment: I don't understand the reason. Hope you need to recheck your answer.

Comment: The question doesn't mention the version of MongoDB. And there are restrictions of using `.` in the column name with the v3.5 and earlier versions.

Comment: Op clearly says it takes forever. I assume which means it's >v3.5. No problem.

Comment: It also says, how to rename... nothing happens

Comment: I haven't used older versions. Out of curiosity, shouldn't it throw syntax error when name contains dot character.

Comment: It's really a configurable setting. I read 15.5 million records, which indicates towards production. It depends whether you want to expose errors or quitely log it. Also, upto what severity/verbosity level.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the slowness:**

> The $rename operator logically performs an $unset of both the old name and the new name, and then performs a $set operation with the new name.

It does two operation first on a document `unset` on old and new name. Then it performs `set` operation. So totally three operations per document.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

And you are actually doing more worse. Because you are converting a field to `nested` one.

**Input doc:**
{
"_id":"",
"key":1
}

**Rename:**

```
db.test.update({}, {
  "$rename": {
    "key": "key1.name"
  }
})
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef718a290c7f76c305aa21c"),
    "key1" : {
        "name" : 1
    }
}
```

It's converted to nested one. You are doing worse because each rename results in 3 operations on a nested doc which in turn contains many fields.

Approximately you are doing `1.6million * 3 * 6` operations on a doc. Hence it is slow.

Comment: I checked it today and all records have changed name. I thought it killed the query because it was too big. Thank you for your answer